# How create dynamic arrays to loop through a list and sum up values based on a criteria

Tags: arrays, vba, dynamic

Below I have a list of “ID” numbers with their associated “Number “and their “values”. I am trying to create sub function that crates a dynamic array that collects all the “Values” that have a “Number” that is equal to and lesser than 30. After the array is filled it is summed and placed under the heading titled “30 or less”.  I have been trying do this using VBA with no luck. I have read a bunch of posts and documents telling me how to do this but I can’t make sense of it. Could someone show me how to get this done. Its driving me crazy and I am sure its simple I eventually want to expand this to do the same with “Numbers ” that are greater than 30 but less than 60 and so on. Thank you

```
    ID  Number  Value
     0   60     100
     1   31     101
     2   12     102
     3   30     103
     4   21     104
     5   60     105
     30 or less
```

Comment: This can be done with a formula using SUMIF() or SUMIFS(). Is there a reason for VBA?

Comment: Please post the VBA code you have written thus far. If you do not have any VBA code yet then you might want to have a look at the following website which explains VBA programming and arrays [For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/index.html): http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_and_arrays.html

Comment: @ScottCraner I need this in a VBA srcipt because I will not know how large the area I will be searching for the condition for numbers<30 will be. I would like for excel to tell the user what the total value is for each  ID  that falls under this numbers<30 condition. This is example is simple because I am using it to practice for a larger problem. The code I will pst is the actual macro I have written so far. The loop is my failed attempt to make a loop do something. I tried to do something simple and failed. Please help

Comment: @ScottCraner I am having trouble adding my code to this post. How would I add it now so you can see what I have attempted already?

Comment: Add it to the original post by clicking the edit.  It can still be done with formulas, although if you data is extremely large than vba will be faster.

Comment: @ScottCraner Hey I have completed the macro. your suggestion of using the sumif function worked just fine. I can't believe the solution was so simple and staring at me in the face the whole time. Thank you for getting my brain working. all the best!

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting this into a new module in VB.

This presumes that your Raw data is in `Sheet(1)` and sorted data will be in a new blank worksheet `Sheet(2)`

```
Sub AddNumbers()
Dim RowNo, ColNo As Long

'Skip Header Row
RowNo = 2

    Do Until Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 1) = ""

        If Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 2) <= 30 Then
        Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1) = "30 or less"
        ColNo = 1
        Sheets(2).Cells((Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1), ColNo) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 3)

        ElseIf Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 2) > 30 And Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 2) <= 60 Then
        Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2) = "Between 30 and 60"
        ColNo = 2
        Sheets(2).Cells((Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row + 1), ColNo) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 3)

        ElseIf Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 2) > 60 And Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 2) <= 90 Then
        Sheets(2).Cells(1, 3) = "Between 60 and 90"
        ColNo = 3
        Sheets(2).Cells((Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).row + 1), ColNo) = Sheets(1).Cells(RowNo, 3)

        End If

        RowNo = RowNo + 1

    Loop

    ' Add Subtotals

    ColNo = 1
    Do Until Sheets(2).Cells(1, ColNo) = ""
    Sheets(2).Cells((Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).row + 1), ColNo).Formula = "=SUM(" & Col_Letter(ColNo) & "2:" & Col_Letter(ColNo) & (Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).row) & ")"
    Sheets(2).Cells((Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, ColNo).End(xlUp).row), ColNo).Font.Bold = True
    ColNo = ColNo + 1
    Loop

End Sub

Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
Dim vArr
vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```